# Empty/blank result file when using shutil to copy a tempfile

Tags: python, temporary-files, shutil

```
import tempfile
import shutil
tmp_f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tmp_f.write("hello world")
shutil.copy(tmp_f.name, "/etc/exports")
```

When I read `/etc/exports`, it is a completely empty file. what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the file:

```
tmp_f.write("hello world")
tmp_f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [closing the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37701385/6243352), it You can use `.flush()` to write the buffer to disk. This may be beneficial in cases when you want to move the file after writing to it, but also want to take advantage of a context manager and `delete=True` (the default mode) to automatically clean up the temp file. For example:

```py
import os
import shutil
import tempfile

destination_path = "hello.txt"
content = "hello world"

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(content.encode("utf-8"))
    temp.flush()
    shutil.copy(temp.name, destination_path)

with open(destination_path) as f:
    print(f.read())

os.remove(destination_path)
```